# Azure Authentication on Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms application that uses azure active directory authentication.
I was using NuGet packet Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client version 3.1.0, and the signature for the `LoginAsync` function for the class `MobileServiceClient` was

```
Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync(UIViewController view, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider);
```

for iOS and a similar signature for Android. Therefore, my Login function on iOS was like this:

```
var window = UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
var current = window.RootViewController;
while(current.PresentedViewController != null) {
    current = current.PresentedViewController;
}
var user = await MSC.LoginAsync(current, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);
return user;
```

Using this function, the library would send the application to the azure active directory web page for login or signup and return a `MobileServiceUser` instance.

That version was working as expected.

However, due to some issues in other parts of the app, I had to update the NuGet packet to a newer version, in this case it's 4.0.2. The Login function changed signature to

```
Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, JObject token);
```

I don't know what to do with the last parameter in order to have the same behavior it used to have. Passing `null` throws an exception and passing a new JObject class does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var user = await MSC.LoginAsync(current, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);

Based on the parameter you passed for logging under Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client v3.1.0, you are using [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) which means that your mobile backend would help you to contact with the related identity provider and directly receive the token, then generate a `authenticationToken` and return to the mobile client for subsequent authorized requests.

As [Azure Mobile Apps Managed SDK Change Log](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) about **Version 4.0.0**:

> - Support of .NET Standard 1.4
> - [Xamarin.Android] Support of server login flow to use Chrome CustomTabs on Android. It supports OAuth 2.0 PKCE extension.
> - [Xamarin.iOS] Support of server login flow to use SafariViewController on iOS. It supports OAuth 2.0 PKCE extension.
> - [UWP] Support of server login flow to use browser on Windows. It supports OAuth 2.0 PKCE extension.

In order to use the same authentication flow under version 4.0.0+, you need to use the following method overload:

```
var user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient
             .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, "{url_scheme_of_your_app}");
```

You could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#redirecturl) for defining the URL scheme for your app on Azure Portal. For detailed steps, you could follow [Add authentication to your Xamarin Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users).

> Task LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider, JObject token);

For the above method overload of `LoginAsync` which would use [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow), for this approach, you need to directly contact with your identity provider for retrieving the token, then you need to send the token to your mobile backend for exchanging a `authenticationToken`.